# Initialize a resource and destroy it until another thread needs it

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm developing a multithread application in C#.

I've a resource I want to initialize when a first thread needs it.

This resource is able to be used by as many threads as it's necessary.

I need to detect, when this resource is free (there is any thread using it) in order to destroy it, and later, when another thread requests it, initialize it again.

Any ideas?

Comment: `initialize when .. [needed]` is straight forward enough using a wrapper class with a singleton pattern or a `static class` .. but `detect, when ... free` could be problematic .. how specifically do you want to achieve this? You could use a reference counting idiom in your wrapper class that `null`'s the reference when the count goes to 0, but you'd have to have the thread code make a 'final' call to the class when it's done with it ... otherwise, you'll probably have to go digging around in the garbage collector to finalize the object/resource so it can be destroyed .. both have drawbacks ..?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about a counter. When the counter is 0, then release it...The problem would run over how to protect the counter of the threads...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
public class SomeClass // basic class for example
{
    public void foo() { }

    public void Close()
    {
        // release any resources you might have open
    }
}

public static class SingletonInstance
{
    private static object m_lock = new object();
    private static SomeClass m_instance = null;
    private static int m_counter = 0;

    public static SomeClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (m_lock) {
                if (m_instance == null) {
                    m_instance = new SomeClass();
                }
                ++m_counter;
            }
            return m_instance;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (m_lock) {
                if (m_counter > 0 && --m_counter == 0) {
                    m_instance.Close();
                    m_instance = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in some other initialization code you could simply say `SingletonInstance.Instance = null;` to have the `SingletonInstance` be statically initialized (since static classes are initialized on the first call to them). Calling `SingletonInstance.Instance = null;` before any thread code will ensure no race conditions happen on the static init of the class; that is, if 2 threads call `SingletonInstance.Instance.foo();`, you can still have a race condition as to who initialized the class first.

Then in your thread code you could do something like the following:

```
void MyThreadFunction()
{
    SingletonInstance.Instance.foo();
    // ... more thread code ...
    SingletonInstance.Instance = null;
}
```

This is a very basic example though, more to illustrate the point and your needs might be slightly different, but the idea is the same.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap your resource in a singleton handler which will destroy it when it is not referenced any longer by any threads.

You can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) for example for how to create such multi-threaded singleton objects. Initialize the resource when the object is created and liberate it in its destructor.